# JMS Serializer exclude public properties

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I have a class I want to serialize, but `exclude` a public property. So far I tried `@Exclude` but I did not work (see Result).

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

**Entity**:

```
class Checkout extends Entity
{
    /**
     * @Exclude()
     */
    public $normalizerCallbacks = [
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
    ];

    ..........
```

**Serialize**:

```
$checkout = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:Checkout')->find($id);

$serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
$data = $serializer->serialize($checkout, 'json');
```

**Result**:

```
{
    normalizer_callbacks: {
        a: 1
        b: 2
    }
}
```

---

Edit: **Trial 2015-09-10 18** --> Not working

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="checkout", options={"collate"="utf8_general_ci"})
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("none")
 */
class Checkout extends Entity
{
    /**
     * @JMS\Exclude();
     */
    public $normalizerCallbacks = [
...
```

Edit: **Trial 2015-09-11 09** (Update 12) --> Configuration

1. Add to `"jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.0"` composer and run update
2. Add `new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle()` to `AppKernel`
3. Add `jms_serializer.camel_case_naming_strategy.class: JMS\Serializer\Naming\IdenticalPropertyNamingStrategy`to `parameters.yml`
4. Then used it as in **Serialize**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try whether you included it correctly:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;
```

and then use it like:

```
@JMS\Exclude();
```

in your annotation.

As well make sure your class is annoted with @ExclusionPolicy("none") (see http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations).

You can as well do it the other way round, specifically @Expose while class is annotated with @ExlucsionPolicy("all").

Make sure to clean your cache before re-testing it.

Comment: I tried the `Trial 2015-09-10 18` version, but still no success!

Comment: hm, tricky, can you show how you configured JMSSerializer and how you load it?

Comment: `Trial 2015-09-11 09` explains what I did, is something missing?

Comment: don't see anything at the moment - did you try any other JMS annotation just to make sure JMS is used here?

Comment: Yes I tried. Everything works as long as it is protected or private, as soon as it is a public field it doesn't.

Comment: I missed that I added `jms_serializer.camel_case_naming_strategy.class: JMS\Serializer\Naming\IdenticalPropertyNamingStrategy` into the `parameters.yml`

Comment: This was a misunderstanding. That's the config parameter I also added, but still it is not working with public methods.